# Plotting dataframes on same plot

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes:

```
a.head()

             AAPL             SPY       date
0  1000000.000000  1000000.000000 2010-01-04
1   921613.643818   969831.805642 2010-02-04
2   980649.393244  1000711.933790 2010-03-04
3   980649.393244  1000711.933790 2010-04-04
4  1232535.257461  1059090.504583 2010-05-04
```

and

```
b.head()

                 date           test
0 2010-01-26 22:17:44  990482.664854
1 2010-03-09 22:37:17  998565.699784
2 2010-03-12 02:11:23  989957.374785
3 2010-04-05 18:01:37  994315.860439
4 2010-04-06 11:06:50  987887.723816
```

After I set the index for `a` and `b` (`set_index('date')`), I can use the pandas `plot()` function to create a nice plot with the date as the x-axis and the various columns as y-values.  **What I want to do is plot two dataframes with different indices on the same figure**.  As you can see from `a` and `b`, the indices are different, and I want to plot them on the same figure.

I tried `merge` and `concat` to join the dataframes together, but the resulting plot is not what I'd like because those functions insert `numpy.NaN` in places where the date is not the same, which makes discontinuities in my plots.  I can use `pd.fillna()` but this is not what I'd like, since I'd rather it just connect the points together rather than drop down to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the same time scale on the x-axis, then you will need timestamps as the index for for `a` and `b` before concatenating the columns.

You can then use [interpolation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#interpolation) to fill in the missing data, optionally with `ffill()` as an additional operation if you want to fill forward past the last observed data point.

```
df = pd.concat([a, b.set_index('date')], axis=1)
df.interpolate(method='time').plot()  # interpolate(method='time').ffill()
```